# Ubuntu behaves weirdly when press some keys

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, brightness, automatic, interrupts

When I press any one of these keys ( <kbd>left-ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>}</kbd>/<kbd>}</kbd> ) it will automatically increases the brightness untill press the alt key.When I press alt key it will stop.
Why this is happening? And how to resolve this problem.

One more thing I have used Linux mint live OS using flash drive to check whether problem is eliminated or not but still it remains as it is.
When I using virtual keyboard there is no such a problem occurs.

I am using HP 245 G7 laptop.
Please help me to sort out this problem.

Thank you

Comment: I think you have already proved it to yourself if it does happen on another Linux os it is most likely the keyboard. Have you tried a different keyboard?

Comment:  Thank you for answering. don't have an extra keyboard.

Comment: You do not have a friend can lend you one for 5 mins? Until you test with another keyboard no sense in trying to pursue this.

Comment: I have friends but they don't have a computer or laptops. One friend is have a laptop but he is far away from my home town. I think I can get the keyboard from a cybercafe.